# Active link, javascript css

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, navigation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#info a.tooltip').addClass('active');
            });
</script>

<ul class="ca-menua">
                    <li><a href="#home" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">O</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#info" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona" id="info">e</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#komp" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">S</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cases" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">F</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#kont" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">@</span></a></li>
                </ul>

a.tooltip.active #info  {
    color: #f3cb12;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

i'm trying to do a active link effect, but I just can't seem to get it right.
The effect is on this link (from page 2, not the frontpage) [Click here to see website.](http://sabinequardon.dk/umami/)

"The active function doesn't work. When you're at a specific page, the navigation item for THAT page should be active.. and it doesn't work now. - it's so you can see WHERE you are."

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.tooltip').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(".ca-menua").load($this.attr('href'));
        $('a.tooltip').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // prevent default link click
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="ca-menua">
               <li><a href="#home" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">O</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#info" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">e</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#komp" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">S</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#cases" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">F</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#kont" class="tooltip"><span class="ca-icona">@</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li a.tooltip.active .ca-icon {
    color: #f3cb12;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: _I just can't seem to get it right_ and this means what exactly?

Comment: What's you're problem exactly?  What isn't working?

Comment: Sorry.. The active function doesn't work. When you're at a specific page, the navigation item for THAT page should be active.. and it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your site I'm getting an error that `$ is not defined` which usually means you've either got your code outside the `$('document').ready()` or you dont' have jQuery included properly.

In fact, when I run your code manually in the console

```
$('a.tooltip').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".ca-menua").load($this.attr('href'));
    $('a.tooltip').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // prevent default link click
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Your desired effect works (shrinking yellow icon).

You just need to put that script AFTER your jQuery include.

Comment: I see the effect on the frontpage now.. but it shouldn't be there, it should be when you click "INFO" it should go to the INFO-page, and then the speakbubble should be yellow and big..